# How to use DisplayMember to get first element of string[] when DataSource is a List<string[]>?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-forms-designer

I'm new to C# and GUI programming, so I have a feeling this is a simple one, but the docs on DisplayMember are confusing me.

```
List<string[]> serverInfo = new List<string[]>();
serverInfo.Add(new string[] { "server one", "1.2.3.4", "12345" });
serverInfo.Add(new string[] { "server two", "1.2.3.4", "12346" });
serverInfo.Add(new string[] { "server three", "1.2.3.5", "12343" });

ComboBox serverPickList = new ComboBox();
serverPickList.DataSource = serverInfo;
serverPickList.DisplayMember = "???";
```

The ComboBox's options should be "server one", "server two", and "server three", but I still want the string[] arrays bound as I'll be processing them.

Comment: You probably have a typo at the end there: `serverList.DataSource` should be `serverPickList.DataSource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why won't you make a class out of it?

```
class ServerInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OtherStuff { get; set; }
    public string OtherStuff2 { get; set; }

    public ServerInfo(string name, string otherStuff, string otherStuff2)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.OtherStuff = otherStuff;
        this.OtherStuff2 = otherStuff2;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
List<ServerInfo> serverInfo = new List<ServerInfo>();
serverInfo.Add(new ServerInfo("server one", "1.2.3.4", "12345"));
serverInfo.Add(new ServerInfo("server two", "1.2.3.4", "12346"));
serverInfo.Add(new ServerInfo("server three", "1.2.3.5", "12343"));

ComboBox serverPickList = new ComboBox();
serverPickList.DataSource = serverInfo;
serverPickList.DisplayMemeber = "Name";
```

Comment: Because I wasn't thinking. Thanks!

Comment: Question about your solution. Is there a reason why you specified `{ get; set; }` for each of the fields, or are you just being explicit?

Comment: @ColinDunklau It's just properties syntax. Better use properties over simple fields, usually.

Answer (score 3):

```
serverPickList.DataSource = serverInfo.Select(x => new { ColA = x[0], ColB =x[1], ColC=x[2] }).ToList();
serverPickList.DisplayMember = "ColA";
```

Comment: I'm currently still scared of Linq, but you still get an upvote.

Comment: This works in the same manner as my solution, except it doesn't require you to actually have a class, because it uses anonymous type. You shouldn't be scared of LINQ - it's really really great. Read about it and learn it thoroughly - it's good for ya.

Comment: Question was how to set List<string[]> as data-source and set display members. Solution is not changing data source :) it is a alternative. this is how to do it:) but OP scared of it. what to do!!!

Comment: @Damith well I don't know what to do. On one hand, your response exactly answered the question, but on the other, I shouldn't be using arrays in the first place. What to do indeed!